# Javascript : Return false is not working : even after I press cancel the code gets executed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, return

**Javascript** : Return false is not working, even after I press cancel the code gets executed

I am trying to execute 2 javascripts with 1 button. When the second script executes, even if I click cancel the code is executed. Below is the code. Can somebody please help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  var TargetBaseControl = null;
  window.onload = function () {
    try {
      //get target base control.
      TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById('<%= this.GridView1.ClientID %>');
    } catch (err) {
      TargetBaseControl = null;
    }
  }

  function TestCheckBox() {
    if (TargetBaseControl == null) return false;
    //get target child control.
    var TargetChildControl = "chkSelect";
    //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
    var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
    if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0 && Inputs[n].checked) return true;
    alert('Please select at least one Request to Close!');
    return false;
  }

  function UpdateConfirmation() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure, you want to close selected request ?") == true) return true;
    else return false;
  }
</script>




<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" 
        OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Close Request" 
         OnClientClick="var b = TestCheckBox(); if (b) UpdateConfirmation(); return b"/>
```

Comment: You return `b` from the event handler, not the return value of `UpdateConfirmation`.

Comment: @Aditya I added some explanation in my answer that you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Shafeeq and all others also

Working code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

             var TargetBaseControl = null;

             window.onload = function () {
                 try {
                     //get target base control.
                     TargetBaseControl =
       document.getElementById('<%= this.GridView1.ClientID %>');
                 }
                 catch (err) {
                     TargetBaseControl = null;
                 }
             }

             function TestCheckBox() 
             {
                 if (TargetBaseControl == null) return false;

                 //get target child control.
                 var TargetChildControl = "chkSelect";

                 //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
                 var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");

                 for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
                     if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&
        Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0 &&
        Inputs[n].checked)
                         return true;

                 alert('Please select at least one Request to Close!');
                 return false;
             }


          function UpdateConfirmation() {
              if (confirm("Are you sure, you want to close selected request ?") == true)


                     return true;

                 else return false;

             }
```

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" 
        Text="Close Request" 
        OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" 
OnClientClick="var b = TestCheckBox(); if (b) return UpdateConfirmation(); return b"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add return while calling your function.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" 
        OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Close Request" 
         OnClientClick="if(TestCheckBox()) return UpdateConfirmation();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use two `asp:Button` (one button is invisible). For Example -

```
//some code
//
function UpdateConfirmation() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure, you want to close selected request ?") == true) 
    document.getElementById('<%= this.btn.ClientID %>').click();//fire hidden button
    else return false;
  }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Close Request" 
   OnClientClick="var b = TestCheckBox(); if (b) UpdateConfirmation(); return b" 
   UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" CssClass="VisibleFalse" TabIndex="-1" />
```

`btn` is hidden button and `btnUpdate` is main button.
Not forget to set `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false`

**Edit** : Use `document.getElementById('<%= this.btn.ClientID %>').click();` instead of `document.getElementById(ClientIDPrefix + "btn").click();`.

It is just a javascript code to fire a button click.

Comment: This won't even fix the problem, though. And it's extra messy, even if it did (by returning false from `OnClientClick`, which it doesn't).